# How to get started in layouting subviews manually?

Tags: xamarin.ios

For testing and practicing I would like to implement a real simple layout manager which just aligns one control next to the other as long as there is space to the right and then goes to next line.

For instance: have a UIView and keep on adding UIButtons with random widths as subviews. one "line" is 40 pixels high. First button is added at (0,0), next one at (120, 0), next one is too wide and will go to (0,40), next one to (80,40) and so on.

The question is not how to do that but **which methods of MonoTouch are involved**? My guess would be to override **LayoutSubViews()** and in there implement my logic to align the controls - is that correct? Do I have to call base.LayoutSubViews()?
Do I have to override anything else? It should of course realign as buttons get removed or added and also if the view itself changes in size.
Do I have to touch **SizeToFit()**, too?

René

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should checkout the MonoTouch [docs for UIView](http://go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=T%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UIView).  Your guess is right in calling LayoutSubViews to position and align your subviews and you'll most likely end up overriding the Draw method on your view.  I think the [TweetStation example](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/TweetStation) does a bit of manual view drawing.  You might want to check that for ideas.